# Install VC Redist 2008 on Windows Server 2000

Tags: windows, kernel, windows-server, visual-c++

I recently set up a server with Windows Server 2000 (I know it´s old, but the hardware of the computer wouldn´t take more than that). Now I installed [xampp](http://www.apachefriends.org/de/xampp-windows.html) which requires the [VC redist package 2008](http://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=29). On the [website](http://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=29) stands it is compatible with Windows 2000 but when I start the setup an error message `The procedure entry point HeapSetInformation could not be located in the dynamic link library KERNEL32.dll`.
How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[HeapSetInformation is implemented in Windows XP/Server 2003](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366705%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), but not in Windows 2000. Upgrade to at least XP or better to 7/8.

```
Requirements

Minimum supported client
    Windows XP [desktop apps only]

Minimum supported server
    Windows Server 2003 [desktop apps only]
```

Comment: There is a comment on that page that states "HeapSet/QueryInformation was added in QFE KB816542 for Windows 2000". Is that true?

Comment: @Karan I have no idea. Win2000 is our of support and so you should no longer use it.

Comment: Who said *I* was using it? :)

Answer (score 1):

You need the Update Rollup 1 update for Windows 2000 SP4 ([KB891861](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=18997)).